# Nested Queries in React Admin

Tags: react-admin

How can we possibly use Nested Queries? It just seems like a big waste when my server fully supports nested queries.

I'm also unable to make a nested input form.

I have a book, that has an author, and the author has a username with a first name and last name.

When creating the book, I want to show a list of Authors, but the optionText needs to be the author's user's first and last name.

I've been trying to figure it out but figured I'd post here since I've had no luck.

Schema:

Book {
 id,
 author_id
}

Author {
 id,
 user_id
}

User {
 id,
 name
}

In this case, When I want to create a new book (SelectInput), I want to show the Author's first and last name (which comes from their user) in the input.

Comment: Can you please share with us a sample schema so that people can understand your issue quicker and be able to help you?

Comment: I added the schema to the post.